# set up NFS two way syncronization

Tags: networking, nfs, distributed-filesystem

I have two servers that I want to "share" the home folder of, such that when I make changes on Server A they appear on Server B and when I make changes on Server B they appear on Server A.

Right now I have NFS set up such that when I make changes on Server A (NFS server) they appear on Server B (NFS client), but not visa versa. Is there something I can do within the NFS config to so that changes B show up on A?

My question is, is there a way to get NFS to do what I want without doing something convoluted, or should I be using another tool to acheive this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you are already aware that NFS doesn't synchronize data across servers or between server and clients. The data you see at server B (NFS Client) is actually data residing on server A (NFS server) and if server A crashes or goes down for any reason the data will not be available on server B

Answer (score 1):

Oopss! So I guess NFS, when set up correctly ^_^, does infact do a two way syncronization.

The problem was that my /etc/fstab was not set up correctly so while I had a /home/ubuntu on Server A and a /home/ubuntu on Server B, I was not mounting  A to B, so they changes I made to B were not reflected on A!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t provide the high availability for your data/files, unless you setup some scheduled jobs using `rsync` like tools and sync between your local directory and the NFS-mounted directory. You can have a look at `Lsyncd` daemon.

Comment: oh wow, thank you! I was looking for high availability. on second look (we're on AWS) amazons elastic file system (EFS) the kind of thing we're looking for. Do you know of anything I can download and set up like I did NFS that provides high avaliability if we don't want to use AWS tools?